# How to configure a Oauth2 authorization server with Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to configure a simple `Authorization Server` based on one of the examples in Github but I got stuck in the token verification part. My current aim is to provide a basic implementation that secures a gateway. What I understand is that Spring automatically makes the redirect to the `AS` in case there is no token in the user session to allow him to log against it. Once logged, it makes the call to authorize the client and then  another one to exchange the given code for a token. In my current implementation, the application is redirected once it has the client code to my client's login page from where it makes a call to `oauth/token` which is then denied access. I don't fully understand where the call to the client's login page is configured or how it makes then the call to `oauth/token` to get the token. My understanding is that this is done automatically by a `OAuth2RestTemplate` and a filter configured automatically by Spring when using the `@EnableOAuth2Sso`

This is my current code.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/user")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userService;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("acme")
                    .secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token","password")
                    .scopes("openid")
                    .autoApprove(".*");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .userDetailsService(userService)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
                throws Exception {
            oauthServer
                    .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                    .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping({"/user"})
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("name", principal.getName());
        return map;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .and().exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }
    }
}
```

With application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/uaa
security.user.password=password
security.ignored=/css/**,/js/**,/favicon.ico,/webjars/**
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

spring.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri: http://localhost:8080/uaa/user
```

And the client application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class ClientApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String home(Principal user) {
        return "Hello " + user.getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ClientApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

With the application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 9999
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8080/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8080/uaa/oauth/authorize
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8080/uaa/user
```

I always get this errors in the browser

```
Name .     Status      Type      Initiator .   Size       Time
login   302 x-www-form-urlencoded   Other   588 B   9 ms
authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9999/login&response_type=code&state=5Q67ay   302     login   380 B   66 ms
login?code=qUKZU5&state=5Q67ay  401 document    :8080/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9999/login&response_type=code&state=5Q67ay   663 B   133 ms
```

And this in the server

```
017-06-27 13:04:33.316 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.316 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.316 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.316 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1c2ae5d1
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.317 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.318 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.318 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2017-06-27 13:04:33.318 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.318 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2017-06-27 13:04:33.318 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5fb2cc06, returned: -1
2017-06-27 13:04:33.319 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /**
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher 
[contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@62266a9a, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/json
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/atom+xml .isCompatibleWith application/json = false
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/x-www-form-urlencoded .isCompatibleWith application/json = false
2017-06-27 13:04:33.321 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/json = true
2017-06-27 13:04:33.324 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@7a85031c
2017-06-27 13:04:33.325 DEBUG 25404 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. 
In the end it was the combination of two things. I needed to add `oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients()` to change the order of filters and allow the authentication based on the user logging information first. And then there was another problem that was related to the property `tokenName` in the client. It had to be `access_token` instead of `oauth_token` to match the name by default Spring uses to find the token in the request.

With those 2 changes it started working.